# No audio encoded with ffmpeg using webm/libvorbis

Tags: ffmpeg, webm

Having issues getting audio to encode to webm.  Tried many different methods and it just ain't happenin.  The commands are printed below before each pass.

I have tried moving the audio commands around, trying different bitrates, different audio commands and have tried it on a couple of different files as well that both have audio.

Encoding these files to MP4 using x264 causes no problems and works just fine and the audio plays, so it appears to be an issue just with webm.  As you can see below, it is a 2-pass encode.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Craig

```
Webm LG PASS 1...........................




    webm_pass1: /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/thedirectory/video613268.mov  -codec:v libvpx -quality good -vf 'scale=640:360 [scaled];movie=/home/thedirectory/watermarks/w640X360.png [logo];[scaled][logo] overlay' -cpu-used 0 -b:v 500k -aspect 16:9 -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -maxrate:v 500k -bufsize:v 1000k -r:v 25/1 -force_fps -threads 0 -an -acodec libvorbis -ac 2 -ab 96k -ar 44100 -pass 1 -f webm -y /dev/null



    ffmpeg version 0.10.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
      built on Mar 11 2013 14:48:26 with gcc 4.6.2 20111027 (Red Hat 4.6.2-2)
      configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-libfaac --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx
      libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
      libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
      libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
      libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
      libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100
      libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
      libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
      libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/thedirectory/video613268.mov':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 537199360
        compatible_brands: qt  
        creation_time   : 2013-02-23 20:04:32
      Duration: 00:00:21.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 114326 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg (jpeg / 0x6765706A), yuvj422p, 1920x1080 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], 112786 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 2997 tbn, 2997 tbc
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2013-02-23 20:04:32
          handler_name    : ?Gestionnaire d?alias Apple
        Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2013-02-23 20:04:32
          handler_name    : ?Gestionnaire d?alias Apple
    Incompatible pixel format 'yuvj422p' for codec 'libvpx', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'
    [buffer @ 0x1f675a0] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:yuvj422p tb:1/1000000 sar:1/1 sws_param:
    [movie @ 0x1f799c0] seek_point:0 format_name:(null) file_name:/home/thedirectory/watermarks/w640X360.png stream_index:0
    [overlay @ 0x1f7c2c0] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scale 0' between the filter 'Parsed_movie_1' and the filter 'Parsed_overlay_2'
    [scale @ 0x1f78d40] w:1920 h:1080 fmt:yuvj422p -> w:640 h:360 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
    [scale @ 0x1f7cde0] w:640 h:360 fmt:rgba -> w:640 h:360 fmt:yuva420p flags:0x4
    [overlay @ 0x1f7c2c0] main w:640 h:360 fmt:yuv420p overlay x:0 y:0 w:640 h:360 fmt:yuva420p
    [overlay @ 0x1f7c2c0] main_tb:1/1000000 overlay_tb:1/25 -> tb:1/1000000 exact:1
    [libvpx @ 0x1f77ce0] v1.0.0
    Output #0, webm, to '/dev/null':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 537199360
        compatible_brands: qt  
        creation_time   : 2013-02-23 20:04:32
        encoder         : Lavf53.32.100
        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=10-42, pass 1, 500 kb/s, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2013-02-23 20:04:32
          handler_name    : ?Gestionnaire d?alias Apple
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> libvpx)
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    frame=  527 fps= 21 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=103    
    video:0kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead -nan%
    Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
    Webm LG PASS 2.......................




    webm_pass2: /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/thedirectory/video613268.mov -codec:v libvpx -quality good -vf 'scale=640:360 [scaled];movie=/home/thedirectory/watermarks/w640X360.png [logo];[scaled][logo] overlay' -cpu-used 0 -b:v 500k  -aspect 16:9  -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -maxrate:v 500k -bufsize:v 1000k -r:v 24/1 -force_fps -threads 0 -an -acodec libvorbis -ac 2 -ab 96k -ar 44100 -pass 2 -f webm -y /media/amazons3/webmlg/video613268.mov.webm



    ffmpeg version 0.10.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
      built on Mar 11 2013 14:48:26 with gcc 4.6.2 20111027 (Red Hat 4.6.2-2)
      configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-libfaac --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx
      libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
      libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
      libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
      libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
      libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100
      libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
      libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
      libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/thedirectory/video613268.mov':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 537199360
        compatible_brands: qt  
        creation_time   : 2013-02-23 20:04:32
      Duration: 00:00:21.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 114326 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg (jpeg / 0x6765706A), yuvj422p, 1920x1080 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], 112786 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 2997 tbn, 2997 tbc
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2013-02-23 20:04:32
          handler_name    : ?Gestionnaire d?alias Apple
        Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2013-02-23 20:04:32
          handler_name    : ?Gestionnaire d?alias Apple
    Incompatible pixel format 'yuvj422p' for codec 'libvpx', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'
    [buffer @ 0x1f2a5a0] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:yuvj422p tb:1/1000000 sar:1/1 sws_param:
    [movie @ 0x1f3bec0] seek_point:0 format_name:(null) file_name:/home/thedirectory/watermarks/w640X360.png stream_index:0
    [overlay @ 0x1f3f2c0] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scale 0' between the filter 'Parsed_movie_1' and the filter 'Parsed_overlay_2'
    [scale @ 0x1f3c8a0] w:1920 h:1080 fmt:yuvj422p -> w:640 h:360 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
    [scale @ 0x1f3fde0] w:640 h:360 fmt:rgba -> w:640 h:360 fmt:yuva420p flags:0x4
    [overlay @ 0x1f3f2c0] main w:640 h:360 fmt:yuv420p overlay x:0 y:0 w:640 h:360 fmt:yuva420p
    [overlay @ 0x1f3f2c0] main_tb:1/1000000 overlay_tb:1/25 -> tb:1/1000000 exact:1
    [libvpx @ 0x1f3ace0] v1.0.0
    Output #0, webm, to '/media/amazons3/webmlg/video613268.mov.webm':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 537199360
        compatible_brands: qt  
        creation_time   : 2013-02-23 20:04:32
        encoder         : Lavf53.32.100
        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=10-42, pass 2, 500 kb/s, 1k tbn, 24 tbc
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2013-02-23 20:04:32
          handler_name    : ?Gestionnaire d?alias Apple
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> libvpx)
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    frame=  506 fps=  7 q=0.0 Lsize=    1610kB time=00:00:21.08 bitrate= 625.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=124    
    video:1389kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 15.952140%
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`-an` option](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Audio-Options) is used to produce output with no audio.  Remove this option if you want audio.

Comment: Thanks mark4o.  I copied part of that command and can't really imagine why the audio was being cut out.  Fail on my part for not finding that myself, but thanks for being gracious enough to answer.  Good on ya.